# OpenProject Docker-Compose: how to skip demo projects creation?

Tags: docker, openproject

I installed OpenProject using Docker-Compose following the official guide and github project:

- https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/docker/
- https://github.com/opf/openproject-deploy

This is the corresponding `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:

volumes:
  pgdata:
  opdata:

x-op-restart-policy: &restart_policy
  restart: unless-stopped
x-op-image: &image
  image: openproject/community:${TAG:-12}
x-op-app: &app
  <<: *image
  <<: *restart_policy
  environment:
    RAILS_CACHE_STORE: "memcache"
    OPENPROJECT_CACHE__MEMCACHE__SERVER: "cache:11211"
    OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT: "${OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT:-}"
    DATABASE_URL: "${DATABASE_URL:-postgres://postgres:p4ssw0rd@db/openproject?pool=20&encoding=unicode&reconnect=true}"
    RAILS_MIN_THREADS: 4
    RAILS_MAX_THREADS: 16
    # set to true to enable the email receiving feature. See ./docker/cron for more options
    IMAP_ENABLED: "${IMAP_ENABLED:-false}"
  volumes:
    - "${OPDATA:-opdata}:/var/openproject/assets"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    <<: *restart_policy
    stop_grace_period: "3s"
    volumes:
      - "${PGDATA:-pgdata}:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-p4ssw0rd}
      POSTGRES_DB: openproject
    networks:
      - backend

  cache:
    image: memcached
    <<: *restart_policy
    networks:
      - backend

  proxy:
    <<: *image
    <<: *restart_policy
    command: "./docker/prod/proxy"
    ports:
      - "${PORT:-8080}:80"
    environment:
      APP_HOST: web
      OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT: "${OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT:-}"
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - frontend

  web:
    <<: *app
    command: "./docker/prod/web"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
      - seeder
    labels:
      - autoheal=true
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080${OPENPROJECT_RAILS__RELATIVE__URL__ROOT:-}/health_checks/default"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s

  autoheal:
    image: willfarrell/autoheal:1.2.0
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    environment:
      AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL: autoheal

  worker:
    <<: *app
    command: "./docker/prod/worker"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
      - seeder

  cron:
    <<: *app
    command: "./docker/prod/cron"
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
      - seeder

  seeder:
    <<: *app
    command: "./docker/prod/seeder"
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - backend
```

Is there an environment variable or a script option that I can use in order to skip the creation of the two demo projects: `Scrum project` and `Demo project` ?

[image]

Related:

- https://community.openproject.org/topics/14926
- https://community.openproject.org/topics/526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no env variable and no script option so there is no built in way to avoid having those projects created in the first place.

However, it is possible to remove the project after they have been created. This can be achieved by modifying the `docker_compose.yml` file if it needs to be recreated or by running a command once afterwards.

The command to be run is:

```
rails runner "::Projects::ScheduleDeletionService.new(user: User.admin.active.first, model: Project.find('your-scrum-project')).call; ::Projects::ScheduleDeletionService.new(user: User.admin.active.first, model: Project.find('demo-project')).call"
```

As this needs to happen in one of the containers you can use the `seeder` container to do so by modifying the `command` of that container to read:

```
command: "./docker/prod/seeder && rails runner \"::Projects::ScheduleDeletionService.new(user: User.admin.active.first, model: Project.find('your-scrum-project')).call; ::Projects::ScheduleDeletionService.new(user: User.admin.active.first, model: Project.find('demo-project')).call\""
```

Alternatively, use `docker-compose run seeder sh -c [that lengthy command]` to achieve the same.

Comment: Hi @ulferts, from the seeder container it does not work.
`/app/bin/rails runner <cmd>` results in   
`/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in require: cannot load such file -- core_extensions (LoadError)`

Comment: Hi @1Z10 can you please prepend the `rails runner` command by a `bundle exec`? So the command would be `bundle exec rails runner [the command in quotes]`. `bundle` will load all the libraries necessary.